# How to specify Object type when I use a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, linq, object, stored-procedures, types

I've a project where I'm using LINQ to SQL. Inside the SQL Server, I've defined a custom stored procedure called `[MyObjectEnabled]` which returns object following a where clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyObject 
WHERE MyDate IS NOT NULL
```

But when I import the stored procedure into my `DataContext`, the type of the result object is `MyObjectEnabledResult`, not `MyObject`.

I need to go to the `DataContext.cs` and edit the returning type manually. But every time I'll import a stored procedure on this `DataContext`, the previous edits will be erased.

So: how can I tell SQL Server to get the returned type right? I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The classes LINQ to SQL creates are partial; so you can make separate code file like `MyObjectEnabledResult.cs` and in this code file have `MyObjectEnabledResult` inherit shared interface and then work just with the shared interface. The same you can do for the LINQ to SQL queries for `MyObject`.

```
// auto-generated by LINQ
public partial class MyObjectEnabledResult
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

// auto-generated by LINQ
public partial class MyObject
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

// your own code behind - ISharedInterface.cs
public interface ISharedInterface
{
  int ID { get; set; }
}

// your own code behind - MyObjectEnabledResult.cs
public partial class MyObjectEnabledResult : ISharedInterface
{
}

// your own code behind - MyObject.cs
public partial class MyObject : ISharedInterface
{
}

// get the db context
var query1 = db.MyObjectEnabled().Cast<ISharedInterface>();
var query2 = from mo in db.MyObjects select (ISharedInterface)mo;
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. Because later I want to works with `MyObject`, not `MyObjectEnabledResult`.

Comment: This means that every Time I edit some parameters, I need to decleare them inside `ISharedInterface`. That's a panic to manage :O

Comment: @markzzz - on the contrary, if your code relies on some object (in this case interface) having some set of properties, this is a great way how to ensure different stored procedures will fetch all the necessary columns.